# Data Reader trimming the leading zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I have a string coming from a stored procedure looks like '001234567'.

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("csp_Bbp_OBN_GetBasePageList", BBConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 sqlCommand.Connection.Open();

// Run the SQL statement, and then get the returned rows to the DataReader.
accReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

 while (accReader.Read())
{    
      BasePage basePage = new BasePage();
      basePage.GroupNum= accReader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
      basePageList.Add(basePage);
      accReader.Close();
      accReader.Dispose();
}
return basePageList;
```

In my case, from the stored procedure I am returning the varchar, after executing and reading it I am getting the value to basePage.GrouNum which is a string. So, I don't see where it is trimming the leading zeros.

Example: GroupNumber in the table is : "001234567"
BasePage.GroupNum after reading from DataReader : "1234567"

But, I do not want the leading zeros being trimmed.
Can any one help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to close the reader inside the loop?

Comment: Nothing in C# indicates that the leading zeros would be trimmed. My guess is that the problem is in the stored proc. Can you please post the proc? Also post the results of EXEC csp_Bbp_OBN_GetBasePageList from SQL Mgmt Studio. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to an integer then format the string going out:

```
basePage.GroupNum = Convert.ToInt32(accReader.GetValue(0)).ToString("000000000")
```

Using the 0's as format specifiers should pad the result string appropriately.

Comment: +1 This is probably the only solution if you can't change the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the stored procedure, make sure it returns a string.  So:

```
select GroupNumber
```

instead of, for example:

```
select cast(GroupNumber as int) as GroupNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if instead of

```
GetValue(0).ToString()
```

you use

```
GetString(0)
```

?

One other thing - get into the habit of wrapping things like commands and readers in [using statements.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) You can avoid the close and dispose stuff and be assured even if your code throws you don't leave anything around.

Comment: If the field is sent as a number, the leading zeroes are lost at the server.  So this won't help.

Comment: The OP says he is returning a varchar from the sproc.

Comment: The field is sent as varchar not as number.. I even executed it to see the results, it has leading zeroes after the stored proc execution. So, I doubt Reader doing some thing wrong.